# Showing error using SLDS Has Error on Apex:Inputfield with Aria-describedby

Tags: apex, visualforce, slds, slds-grid

I am using the SLDS in visualforce page and trying to display error next to the component by following [this.](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#Error)

But `aria-describedby` does not work with `<Apex:inputfield>` and throws error.

Here's the code,

```
 <div class="slds-form__row">
     <div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
         <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal slds-is-editing slds-has-error">
             <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="stacked-form-element-id-01">
             <abbr class="slds-required" title="required">* </abbr>{!$ObjectType.Case.fields.Billing_EFT_Action__c.Label}</label>
                 <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                     <apex:actionRegion >
                         <apex:inputfield value="{!caseObj.Billing_EFT_Action__c}" id="billingaction" aria-describedby="form-error-01" styleClass="slds-input">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  rerender="buttons" />
                         </apex:inputfield>
                     </apex:actionRegion>  
                  </div>
              <div class="slds-form-element__help" id="form-error-01">This field is required</div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

If I change the `<apex:inputfield>` to `<input>`, I lose the functionality of using the formula expression to fetch the value directly from the controller. Also, I need to be able to call the JS function and `reRender` an output panel `onChange` of the field value. Is there any way to show the error right below the field using slds with  OR I am better of using the `<input>` and then call JS function onchange and then render the Output panel using action function from JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pass through custom attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) to place the attribute:

```
<apex:inputField html-aria-describedby="form-error-01" ... />
```